# pythonのモジュール、ライブラリの意味の違い

Tags: python

1.pythonのモジュール、ライブラリの意味の違いを教えてください。

2.scikitlearn ではfrom sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
と書いてtrain_test_split関数を読み込みますが、pandasではfrom pandas import read_csv
と書いてread_cav関数を読み込みます。scikitlearnとpandasは両方ともライブラリらしいですが、同じ関数なのになぜtrain_test_splitはskitlearnの二階層下にあって、read_csvはpandasの一階層下にあるんですか？ライブラリ⇒モジュール⇒関数と思っていたのですが違うのでしょうか？

以上2点回答お願いします。

Comment: 私も気になっていた疑問です。なぜ２階層下のファイルに入れるんでしょうか。自分もプログラムを進めて思ったのはコーディング上そうなっていた方が都合がいいという事か、抽象度が高いものから低いものへと階層構造を形成しているのかもしれません。

Comment: 階層構造を1階にするか2階にするか、3階にするのかは設計者の気分の問題だと思います。モジュール内の関数とクラスが密に結合している(例：この関数を使用している人はこのクラスも使用しています)場合は1階のほうがいいですし、逆に関係のないモジュールは分離したほうが読みやすいです。関係ないコードを無視してほしいものだけを使えますからデバッグとかもしやすい。(分割統治法の考え方ですね)

Comment: @naoki fujita 勉強になりました。

Answer (score 3):

1.
モジュール：モジュール,関数,クラス,変数などの定義の集まり
ライブラリ：モジュール,関数,クラス,変数などの定義の集まり
ライブラリという言葉はpythonの言語仕様には規定がないです。非常に広い領域で使われています。Cの標準ライブラリとか、C#の.netのクラスライブラリとか。ライブラリは概ねプログラマによって呼び出されることを主目的として書かれた汎用的なプログラム(API)のことをさします。
モジュールはpythonの言語仕様として定められているのでこちらのほうが意味がはっきりしています。関数やクラスが入ってたりします。モジュールを複数入れたものをpythonではパッケージと呼ぶことがありますが、内部的には複数のファイル(モジュール)をまとめ上げるモジュールのようです。
2.
ここではsklearnはパッケージ、つまり階層構造を持つモジュールです。
pandasは一層下にread_csvを持つモジュールです。
モジュール.関数も、モジュール.モジュール.関数も許されるということです。

```
import sklearn
import pandas
type(sklearn) #->module と表示されるがパッケージと呼ぶことが多い
type(sklearn.model_selection) #->module
type(pandas) #->module
type(train_test_split) #->function
```